# Size of default sharepoint team sites

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Whats the exact size of the new SharePoint(2013,2016) team site/subsite? The site containing just a default data and nothing customized, no documents etc

Answer (score 0):

We can use the PowerShell below to get site size.

```
$spsite = Get-SPSite "http://sp2013/sites/team"
$spsite | select @{Name="Size"; Expression={"{0:N2} MB" -f ($_.Usage.Storage/1000000)}}
```